# Return top 2 and bottom 1 columns of ranked dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to return row-wise the top two records by value, and the bottom record by value as additional columns, or a separate dataframe entirely (either or).

Lets say I have the following dataframe of values:

```
example = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3],
                        'b':[6, 5, 8, 0, 3, 2, 1], 
                        'c':[1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7],
                        'd':[4, 6, 5, 3, 9, 11, 3],
                        'e':[8, 0, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3]})
example

   a  b  c   d  e
0  3  6  1   4  8
1  8  5  4   6  0
2  5  8  5   5  5
3  3  0  3   3  2
4  2  3  6   9  1
5  1  2  2  11  1
6  3  1  7   3  3
```

Since I want to find the top values, I end up ranking this dataframe, columnwise with no repeating in rank.

```
rank_df = example.rank(axis=1, method='first', ascending=False)
rank_df

     a    b    c    d    e
0  4.0  2.0  5.0  3.0  1.0
1  1.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  2.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
3  1.0  5.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
4  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  5.0
5  4.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  5.0
6  2.0  5.0  1.0  3.0  4.0
```

Now lastly, I would like to pull in the column names for the ranks, and pull out into a dataframe the top two and bottom one. For example, row 0 has rank 1 in column e, rank 2 in column b, and rank 5 in column c, so the three columns would be e, b, c.

**Expected Output:**

```
   top_1, top_2, bottom_1
0  e      b      c
1  a      d      e
2  b      a      e
3  a      c      b
4  d      c      e
5  d      b      e
6  c      a      b
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values and get columns names by indexing:

```
a = example.columns.to_numpy()[(-example).to_numpy().argsort()]
#if use lower version of pandas
#a = example.columns.values[(-example).values.argsort()]
print(a)

[['e' 'b' 'd' 'a' 'c']
 ['a' 'd' 'b' 'c' 'e']
 ['b' 'a' 'c' 'd' 'e']
 ['a' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'b']
 ['d' 'c' 'b' 'a' 'e']
 ['d' 'b' 'c' 'a' 'e']
 ['c' 'a' 'd' 'e' 'b']]
```

And then select first, second and last column and convert to DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a[:, [0,1,-1]], index=df.index, columns=['top_1', 'top_2', 'bottom_1'])
print (df)
  top_1 top_2 bottom_1
0     e     b        c
1     a     d        e
2     b     a        e
3     a     c        b
4     d     c        e
5     d     b        e
6     c     a        b
```